# Android: Qualcomm's QCAR (Vuforia) SDK with min3D Framework (or other 3D-Model/Animation Loader/Renderer)

Tags: android, animation, augmented-reality, java-3d, qcar-sdk

I would like to use Qualcomm's Augmented Reality SDK (Vuforia) with the [min3D](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) library and load animations with md2 files. How can I merge QCAR (Vuforia) with min3D? How assigning the projection and modelview matrix of QCAR (Vuforia) to min3D? So that the scene is rendered correct in min3d.glsurfaceview? Has anyone developed an example? How is your experience?

Edit: For examples and experiences with other 3rd party rendering librarys like [jPCT-AE](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/) or [ModelRenderer](http://code.google.com/p/android-gl/downloads/list), i am also very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same thing as "yogi" said. `jpct-ae` and `qcar` together are awesome. I used a single `GLSurfaceView` and brought the `ModelView` matrix and the actual video resolution from native code to Java. Then you can easily load an `md2` file along with animation.

You can watch the result here:

http://youtu.be/chsHh0pEhzw

Comment: i saw your video...awesome job

Answer (score 2):

after a long struggle i succeded to integrate Jpct library with vuforia,it's a long code ,if you still stucked ask specific questions i will help

Comment: first try to use jpct glsurface over vuforia glsurface,then pass modelview matrix from native code to jpct.ask any problms you face.