# QCAR-sdk and MD2 files

Tags: file, 3d, qcar-sdk

I was wondering if it was possible to load animated 3D models into Qualcomm's AR-SDK using the MD2 format. I wouldn't ask but it says [here](http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2011/05/01/starting-an-android-ar-project-with-qcar/) that QCAR only works with .h files. 
Also if you think that there is a better format that I could use (that supports animation) feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score 3):

I did the same thing as "yogi" said. `jPCT-AE` and `QCAR` together are awesome. I used a single `GLSurfaceView` and brought the `ModelView` matrix and the actual video resolution from native code to Java. Then you can easily load an `MD2` file along with animation.

You can watch the result here:

http://youtu.be/chsHh0pEhzw

Answer (score 2):

With the [min3d libarary for Android](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) it is possible to load md2-files. I have not yet can be merge. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242454/android-qualcomms-qcar-vuforia-sdk-with-min3d-framework-or-other-3d-model-a) I had asked a question about. In [QCAR Forum](https://ar.qualcomm.at:443/arforums/showthread.php?t=59&referrerid=11163) some say, that they have it merge.

Answer (score 1):

after a long struggle i succeded to integrate [Jpct](http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#jPCT-AE_-_a_port_of_jPCT_to_Android) library with vuforia,it's a long code ,if you ask specific questions i will help