# How to render animated models (e.g. MD2) in QCAR Android SDK?

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, qcar-sdk

I know lots of work is going around QCAR SDK, I tried many things myself. Can anyone suggest me how to render an animated models like md2 in it?

I tried a lots of things like using 3rd party rendering library on top of QCAR but I didn't succeed. Any help in this direction will be a great help. I tried in QCAR forum but I got no solution. Hope you guys have tried something like that.
thanks for your time and help.

Comment: solved:for anyone who is facing same problem follow my  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242454/android-qualcomms-qcar-vuforia-sdk-with-min3d-framework-or-other-3d-model-a/12158889#12158889)