# Playing animated images with vuforia qualcomm

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to run an animation over the AR camera view, something like a animation where a balloon floats over the actual view, it will be based on detection of marker, but need not be positioned exactly over the marker.

I have seen the videoplay demo and tried modifying it, but I can see 3 major roadblocks, 1. a video inside camera view is supported only in android version 4.0 and above, whereas I would like to support from 2.3; 2. It plays videos and not animations, videos are like rectangular boxes, where as my requirement is to add a specific object like ballon, and rest of the area should be as per camera view; 3. the animation need not play exactly over the marker

I am open to work with native android or unity, though with unity I saw another limitation it will support mobile devices powered by an ARMv7 only, which might again be a roadblock.

I am guessing a good approach might be to do animation in unity (or some other tool like maya) and integarte to eclipse based android app.

Any pointers regarding how can I achive this simple animation effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using unity. The app was created in unity and then transported to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

you can use md2 models which have animation and they are very light. Qcar is a good library to do AR stuff,i am using it for a long time.See my ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158889/1206201) to combine another library(Jpct-ae) to do this with Qcar .

Answer (score 1):

Why don you try to do the same without unity?
Try simply with Vuforia + Eclipse:
http://devel-open.blogspot.com.ar/2012/10/vuforia-eclipse-ubuntu.html